# Strange struggle with the select_by_index() method of Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a small program to automate something that requires me to use Selenium to log into a web-site, identify a drop box, make a selection from the drop box and proceed with a few other web-clicks. Fairly simple stuff.

But I am experiencing a very strange struggle with select_by_index() method. Here's my code snippet. Have used hard-coded values here to focus on my problem. The *Select()* call goes through. I can even see that *date_drop_box.options[i].text* is loaded with all the values from the drop-down. But strangely, the *select_by_index(i)* fails (basically hits the "except" code block that I have in my full program! To narrow the problem down, I commented out that line of code and put a pdb.set_trace() there. And every time there was a break, I called the select_by_index method explicitly from the debugger and continued the flow and things just worked!

HELPPPPPP!

Simplified code snippet:

```
date_drop_box = Select(web_driver.find_element_by_id('my-id'))
print(date_drop_box.options[3].text)
date_drop_box.select_by_index(3)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not go through". What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Please read why a [Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: If the program works in debug mode then you have a timing issue. Are the values of this dropdown populated dynamically? Try with a suitable sleep before the index method. If it works put in a more robust explicit wait condition

Comment: Will do. First-timer (hope to be here often!) here so yet to get used to the DOs and DONTs

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper. I put a range of waits....from 3 seconds all the way to 10. But I have reason to believe that it may not be a simple timing issue because the values of the dropdown are loaded. There are 15 entries in the list and all of them are loaded. I put a print statement (loop of len(date_drop_box)) of all the text values (date_drop_box.options[i].text) before calling the select_by_index() function and it prints out all 15 entries.

Comment: Can you provide the error that occurs when trying to `select_by_index()`?

Comment: PixelEinstein, the error is - selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <select id="myid" name="myid"> is not clickable at point (142.56666564941406,515.2833251953125) because another element <html> obscures it

Comment: And my code is very simple too:

time.sleep(15)
date_drop_box = Select(web_driver.find_element_by_id('my-id'))
date_drop_box.select_by_index(3)

driver.back()
time.sleep(15)
date_drop_box = Select(web_driver.find_element_by_id('my-id'))
date_drop_box.select_by_index(2)
time.sleep(10)

driver.back()
time.sleep(15)
date_drop_box = Select(web_driver.find_element_by_id('my-id'))
date_drop_box.select_by_index(1)
time.sleep(10)


driver.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without relevant `HTML` and the entire `Exception` updated in the question, I will do my best to answer this.

Based on your comment under the question, the `Exception` you are receiving is `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <select id="myid" name="myid"> is not clickable at point (142.56666564941406,515.2833251953125) because another element <html> obscures it`

Which means that the element is present in the `DOM` , but it's currently not in view to be selected. I have ran into this issue before and solved it by scrolling to the option before executing the click. Please try this:

```
element = date_drop_box.options[i]
web_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
date_drop_box.select_by_index(i)
```

If this does not work, please update **Question** with relevant HTML.

Comment: thanks a lot for the interest and help. Tried the suggested code changes. I continue to get the same error. What is a way that I can attach the HTML (sorry, I am new to this forum)? Simply cop-and-paste it in-line here?

Comment: @SachinDesai, You would add the relevant HTML to the **Question** by editing you question and adding it in. Please make sure to keep the standard formatting of the HTML the same.

Comment: After grappling with this problem for several days and trying various solutions, I hit upon the cause of my issue. Turns out, the calls to `Select()` and `select_by_index()` were being done right. But for some reason, the `select_by_index()` call failure has to do with the fact that I had set the window size (of the browser) to a smaller size immediately after opening it with a `driver.set_window_size(400,600)` call. Once I commented that out, it started working. I am still unable to explain the connection though